# How to upgrade Ubuntu release 19.10 to 20.04 LTS?

Tags: upgrade, updates

I would like to upgrade my Ubuntu release 19.10 to 20.04 LTS. How can I do this? I tried the software update and upgrade, but that would just upgrade my packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release). Because 19.10 has already gone EOL, the best path may be to install 20.04 cleanly. If you don't plan to upgrade every 6-9 months, you might consider using only LTS releases instead of standard releases which have a faster release cadence.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades